# How to change "Price"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

[image: My Image]

In woocommerce I would like to change "Price:" to "Cena:" (from eng to polish). Where can I change it? Which file? I didn't find this in woocommerce templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one and put it in your `functions.php`.

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_price_woo', 999, 3 );

function change_price_woo( $translated, $text, $domain ) {

$translated = str_ireplace( 'Price:', 'Cena:', $translated );

return $translated;
}
```